# Use websocket in java web application

Tags: java, websocket

My web application was developed by JDK 1.6. Now i want to use websock, but jdk 6 does not support this. Please introduce me to use which library to do websocket for jdk6 and how to configure in web.xml. I tried using Jetty version 9 but i still can not implement

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. It has both implementation of websocket at server side and client side.

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket